# SF2: How to custom the form type messages?

Tags: regex, symfony, entity, constraints, validation

I want to know how I can modify the error message on my ContactType.
It's possible directly in the Type ?

My current code:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       //...
    }

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'My custon message.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 2), array('message' => 'My custon message.'))
            ),
            'email' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'My custon message.')),
                new Email(array('message' => 'My custon message.'))
            ),
            'subject' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'My custon message.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 10), array('message' => 'My custon message.'))
            ),
            'message' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'My custon message')),
                new Length(array('min' => 5))
            )
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

Thanks you all for your helping.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommend to change the message of the assertion instead, but you can also use the `invalid_message` setting of a form type.